# Fetching foreign key reference variable from an entity return empty list in jpa

Tags: java, oracle, hibernate, jpa

I was fetching the values from an entity including a foreign key reference. Table have values in all columns except the foreign key. But the returned result list was empty.

The entities are,

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "Student")
public class Student
{
   @Id
   @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE)
   private Integer id;

   @Column(name = "name", nullable=false)
   private String name;

   @OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "Mark")  
   private Mark mark;

   //some other fields, getters and setters
}

@Entity
@Table(name = "Mark")
public class Mark
{
   @Id
   @Column(name = "id", nullable=false)
   private Integer id;

   @Column(name = "grade", nullable=false)
   private String grade;

   @Column(name = "totalMark", nullable=false)
   private Double totalMark;

   //some other fields, getters and setters
}
```

The query is,

```
select s.id,s.name,s.mark.grade from student s where s.name='Ramesh';
```

If the student id is not present in the mark entity means the result list from the above query is empty. If I fetch the id in mark instead of grade then I got the result list.

I don't why please anyone help me and give me solution for this problem. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your query will list student who has grade . It performs inner joining between student and grade .You can try **left joining** to solve this problem . This query will result all students .

```
select s.id,s.name,m.grade from student s left join s.mark m where s.name='Ramesh';
```

Comment: By default  "select s.id,s.name,s.mark.grade from student s where s.name='Ramesh'; "  this query will perform inner join . So students who is not having marks are not listed